# "pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file" after moving to mac

Tags: python, pandas

In Windows 8, the script works fine. After I moved script and data.csv to work in my mac, I keep getting error: "pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file."

The script and data are in the same folder as

```
"/Users/myname/Downloads/test/testimport.py"
"/Users/myname/Downloads/test/test2.csv"
```

I've tried many file locations to read the csv but nothing works.

```
file_loc = "../test/test2.csv"
# as well as "../test2.csv", "/test2.csv", "/Users/myname/Downloads/test/test2.csv"

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file_loc)
exp_mat = df.as_matrix()
print exp_mat
```

How can I read the csv here? Is it wrong location problem or is csv filetype in mac not compatible?

---

Here is OS X El Capitan. Full error is

```
h143% python testimport.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_importexcel.py", line 24, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(file_loc)
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 389, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 730, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 923, in _make_engine
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1390, in __init__
self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 538, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:6171)
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

Data (copying from Number is like)

```
x   time    value
445.1207    0.003626    21935450
445.1203    0.011099    36700932
445.1203    0.017235    35722172
445.1203    0.022958    33623668
445.1203    0.028689    33500360
352.3396    37.180567   307886720
352.3396    37.185836   303264100
352.3396    37.191101   292523810
```

Comment: What is separator of csv?

Comment: @jezrael I created table by Excel in windows so I didn't input any separators at that time. But now when I open it in Atom, it has comma as separator.

Comment: What about encoding? `UTF-8` ?

Comment: @jezrael yes, encoding in Atom is UTF-8

Comment: Hmmm, I check save as dialog in excel and there is option `csv` ('Macintosh'). It can works nice I think.

Comment: @jezrael I think I chose save as csv ('Macintosh') at that time. But now I don't have any Windows machines around. Is there anything I can do right here with my mac?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test it, I never working with csv in mac. But it seems `mac` read files as empty. But if separator is `whitespace`, need add `delim_whitespace=True`

Comment: I never had issues working with Pandas CSVs on my mac. Looking at the error that is due to the sep value. Try using delim_whitespace=True and header=0